# Is my hack to store users' private data on Cloudant secure?

Tags: security, authentication, couchdb, cloudant

I want to store users' private information on a CouchDB in Cloudant - i.e. each user should be able to read and update only his own document.
Usually such information is saved in the _users db, but I really liked Cloudant's API keys and don't want to manage users and passwords myself.

I found several solutions in this wiki:
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/PerDocumentAuthorization
but they all had limitations:

- "Database per User" is really annoying to manage.
- "Smart Proxy" takes the fun out of CouchDB and CouchApps.
- "Document encryption on a per user basis" is way too complicated.

Then I figured out a new solution - I created a database (called "test") and configured all the users as `_writer`s, without any `_reader`s.
To prevent users from writing over each others documents, I set `validate_doc_update` in my `_design/app` to:

```
function(newDoc, savedDoc, userCtx) { 
  if ((userCtx.roles.indexOf('_admin') < 0) && (userCtx.name != newDoc._id)) { 
    throw ({unauthorized: "cannot access others"});
  } 
}
```

To let the users' read their own document, I wrote the following update function (called "update_hack"):

```
function(doc, req) { 
    return [doc, toJSON(doc)];
}
```

Now, every user can "get" his document by sending a POST request to:

```
http://<username>:<password>@<host>/db/_design/app/_update/update_hack/<username>
```

If the user tries to send a POST request to a document of a different user, say:

```
http://<username>:<password>@<host>/test/_design/app/_update/update_hack/someoneelse
```

then he'll get an `{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"cannot access others"}` response for trying to "update" the document.

There is some inefficiency in this trick because every time a user "gets" his document, the revision of the document has to change.
There is also the issue of realizing whether a username exist or not by sending POST requests (if the document does not exist, a "null" will be returned).

Do you see any security flaws in this trick?

Is there a better way to store private document per user when the users are generated via API keys? (Even if there is, I still think that my trick is cool).

Comment: I would directly ask Cloudant. They are pretty responsive.

Comment: This is a terribly clever hack! I think a nice touch would be to set a "last accessed" timestamp on the document each read this way ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no

Long answer: You are using something for access control which was not designed to be used as access control. This is a security anti pattern and has time after time resulted in security breaches. For example how do you ensure error messages etc do not leak data? What about updating documents?

Most notably the "write only" security approach has resulted in many security breaches. For example in file servers.

Also by using POST for GETting data you loose all caching.

Nevertheless - a very clever hack you came up with. But I would strongly advise against trusting it's security.